# Google Maps directions duration in traffic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know there is a way to request for duration in traffic using Google Maps API but it's restricted to Google Maps Business users and is subject to availability.

My question is, is there a way to account for traffic using a normal Google maps directions request? Or if not, is there a general time buffer we can add to the returned estimate?

Comment: Hello Ron, Did you find an answer to your question? I am also in search of a similar utility that could provide the traffic information for a particular route.

Comment: So far I haven't found a solution for this and it is still not available in my country.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Well I found BingMapsUI to be more useful in this context. It provides pretty good information about traffic for a particular route. It also gives information on Road Block, Accidents etc.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **no**.

However, I must also say thay the [DirectionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsRequest) object specification does no longer include the parameter `durationInTraffic`.

As of November 2015 [it says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#322):

> The durationInTraffic request field is now deprecated. It was
>   previously the recommended way **for Google Maps APIs Premium Plan
>   customers** to specify whether the result should include a duration that
>   takes into account current traffic conditions. You should now use the
>   drivingOptions field instead.

It also says:

> The Directions service and the Distance Matrix service now return the
>   predicted time in traffic (in response field duration_in_traffic) when
>   the travel mode is driving.  To receive predicted travel times,
>   include a **drivingOptions** object literal in the request, specifying
>   a current or future departureTime. [...]  The duration_in_traffic **is
>   available only to Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers**.

Answer (score -1):

check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) out.I guess What you are requesting is possible using **GOOGLE MAPS API V3**  Direction Request will return Something like this.

```
{
 origin: LatLng | String,
 destination: LatLng | String,
  travelMode: TravelMode,
 transitOptions: TransitOptions,
 unitSystem: UnitSystem,
durationInTraffic: Boolean,
waypoints[]: DirectionsWaypoint,
 optimizeWaypoints: Boolean,
 provideRouteAlternatives: Boolean,
avoidHighways: Boolean,
 avoidTolls: Boolean
region: String
 }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I know it is possible using the code you mentioned above because I use the same code. The problem is that it does not account for traffic conditions unless you're a business user.

Answer (score -1):

For Google API, you have to have API for Work to obtain traffic info. Bing provides the traffic info for basic account. You can either use Bing Map, or you can extract traffic info (basically, just the duration in traffice from A to B) from Bing to Google Map

Comment: you can't really do that, as you'd have to match the path from Bing to the one from Google.